# NextJS + React-query, query is lost, disappears from react-query-devtools when second time click on link of same page

Tags: next.js, react-query

react-query hook

```
export const useSearchClient: UseSearchClient = (filters) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['clients'],
    queryFn: queryFn(filters),
    enabled: false,
  })
}
```

client component

```
const { data, error, isLoading, refetch } = useSearchClient(filters)

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch()
  }, [refetch])
```

Client Page

```
const ClientsPage: NextPage = () => <Client />

export default ClientsPage
```

Sidebar

```
import Link from 'next/link'
```

```
<Link href="/client">client</Link>
```

on page load, i can see query in devtools. when click on client Link from sidebar again. and query is lost, disappears from react-query-devtools when second click on link of same page.

on link click when i am same page. query should not lost.

Comment: sounds like an unstable query client, but your code doesn't show everything. The usage of refetch in an effect with disabled queries is also not idiomatic. https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#why-are-updates-not-shown

Comment: Thank @TkDodo. I got answer. My QueryClient was not stable.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is very similar to my case, my data was being fetched and disappeared instantly at the first load, within a second. After deep dive into my code and comparing it with my last project, I found that `QueryClient` cannot be inside the app function. Below is the example

Wrong Example

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {


    const queryClient = new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
            queries: {
                retry: false,
                refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            },
        },
    });

    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}
```

Correct Example

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            retry: false,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        },
    },
});

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}
```

I know that is too late, but hopefully it help somebody else.